# How to preform a uniform convergence test on a sequence of functions with intervals that depend on $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, uniform-convergence

Let
$$
f_{n}(x) =
 \begin{cases}
  \dfrac{1}{x}  &  \dfrac{1}{n}\leq x \leq 2 \\[4pt]
  0 & 0 < x < \dfrac{1}{n}
 \end{cases}
$$

$f_{n}(x)$ converges point-wise to $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, $x\in(0,2]$. How to test whether this convergence is uniform?

Comment: Try to identify the minimal $N(x)$ such that if $n \geq N(x)$ then $f_n(x)=1/x$. Then notice that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} N(x) = +\infty$.

Comment: Could you explain more please.

Comment: Not until you add some of your own efforts to the question, no.

Comment: I  would but I am not sure what your first comment means.

Comment: @Ian, How to find $N(x)$?

Comment: @Jake It amounts to finding the minimal $N$ such that if $n \geq N$ then $1/n<x$. Since this is monotone this is just finding the minimal $N$ such that $1/N<x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uniform convergence, given $\epsilon > 0$, we need to find $N$ such that $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ and $n\geq N$.  Every $f_n(x)$ differs from $f(x)=1/x$ on the interval $(0,1/n)$ where $f_n(x)=0$ and so the difference is $1/x$.  This difference is not bounded at all for any $n$ (becoming infinite as $x\to 0$), so it can't be bounded by some $\epsilon$.

Comment: How to show mathematically that it can't be bounded by some $\epsilon$?

Comment: For each given $n$, there is an interval $(0,1/n)$ in which the difference is $1/x$.  Because that interval goes up to zero, we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=1/x>\epsilon$ for small enough $x$, specifically for $x<\min(1/\epsilon,1/n)$.

Comment: @ForgotALot, Would $f_{n}$ be uniformly convergent to $1$ if we replaced $1/x$ by $1$ for $\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq 2$?

Comment: If you keep $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\in (0,1/n)$, no, because $f(x)=1$ for all $x$, and so $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=1$ for $x\in (0,1/n)$.  You then can't satisfy the condition $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ and $n\ge N$ when $\epsilon<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Uniform convergence of $(f_n)_n$ to $f$ on a domain $D$ is equivalent, by definition, to $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{x\in D}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0.$ In the Q, with $D=(0,2]$ we have $\sup_{x\in D}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{0<x<1/n}1/x=\infty$ for every $n$.